# Confused about `search_as_you_type` ngram subfields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add "search as you type" functionality to a field in Elasticsearch called `email_address`. My understanding [from the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/search-as-you-type.html) is that if I create a `search_as_you_type` field, it should automatically create ngram sub-fields optimized for finding partial matches.

However, it doesn't seem to be working the way I would expect, and I don't seem to get the benefits I would expect from this special field type.

First, I created an index with:

```sh
$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT http://localhost:9200/mytestindex -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email_address": {"type": "search_as_you_type"}
    }
  }
}
'
```

When I request the newly created email field, this is what I see:

```sh
$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_mapping/field/email_address | json_pp
{
   "mytestindex" : {
      "mappings" : {
         "email_address" : {
            "full_name" : "email_address",
            "mapping" : {
               "email_address" : {
                  "max_shingle_size" : 3,
                  "type" : "search_as_you_type"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, I populated with some sample data:

```sh
$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_doc -d '
{"email_address": "sam@example.com"}'

$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_doc -d '
{"email_address": "sally@example.com"}'

$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_doc -d '
{"email_address": "jane@example.com"}'

$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_doc -d '
{"email_address": "samantha@example.com"}'
```

The official docs recommend searching with a `bool_prefix` `multi_match` with the following fields: `email_address`, `email_address._2gram`, and `email_address._3gram`. Curious to experiment with the subfields, I've tested searches that only include them, but I can't get any results back:

```sh
$ curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sa",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "email_address._2gram",
        "email_address._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}
' | json_pp

{
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [],
      "max_score" : null,
      "total" : {
         "value" : 0,
         "relation" : "eq"
      }
   },
   "took" : 4,
   "_shards" : {
      "skipped" : 0,
      "successful" : 1,
      "total" : 1,
      "failed" : 0
   },
   "timed_out" : false
}
```

I've tried various lengths of partial queries (`s`, `sa`, `sam`, etc) but I never get any results.

When I perform the same search but only include the `email_address` field itself, I get all the results I would expect:

```sh
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/mytestindex/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sa",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "email_address"
      ]
    }
  }
}
' | json_pp
{
   "timed_out" : false,
   "hits" : {
      "max_score" : 1,
      "total" : {
         "relation" : "eq",
         "value" : 3
      },
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_index" : "mytestindex",
            "_id" : "gEbkCXUBC6_J-EeLAygM",
            "_score" : 1,
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_source" : {
               "email_address" : "sam@example.com"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index" : "mytestindex",
            "_source" : {
               "email_address" : "sally@example.com"
            },
            "_score" : 1,
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "gUbkCXUBC6_J-EeLWigu"
         },
         {
            "_index" : "mytestindex",
            "_id" : "jUb5CXUBC6_J-EeL1ij1",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_score" : 1,
            "_source" : {
               "email_address" : "samantha@example.com"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "took" : 2,
   "_shards" : {
      "failed" : 0,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "successful" : 1,
      "total" : 1
   }
}
```

As a result, I don't understand what benefit the `_2gram` and `_3gram` subfields are providing. Did I set something up incorrectly? Or am I confused about the actual purpose of those fields?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The [search_as_you_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html) field type is a text-like field that is
> optimized to provide support for queries that serve an as-you-type
> completion use case

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{"title": "how shingles are actually used"}
```

**Analyze API**

**The default tokenizer in elasticsearch is the “standard tokenizer”, which uses the grammar-based tokenization technique**

The individual tokens produced for the text are

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "how",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "shingles",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "are",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "actually",
      "start_offset": 17,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "used",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

To produce shingles of 3 words

```
POST/_analyze

{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "shingle",
      "min_shingle_size": 3,
      "max_shingle_size": 3,
      "output_unigrams":false
    }
  ],
  "text": "how shingles are actually used"
}
```

The tokens generated are:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "how shingles are",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "shingles are actually",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "are actually used",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

> title._3gram - Wraps the analyzer of my_field with a shingle token
> filter of shingle size 3

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "shingles are actually",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "title._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "how shingles are actually used"
        }
      }
    ]
```

In your case, considering `"text": "samantha@example.com"`, the individual tokens generated are: `samantha` and  `example.com`

When creating a shingle of 2 words, tokens generated are:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "samantha example.com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**So when you are searching with `sa` it will not match, since no tokens are generated corresponding to it.
When using multi-match with bool prefix query (on `email_address` field, it matches because of `" type": "bool prefix"`. Read this to know more about [Match bool prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html#query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query).**

If you want to query with `sa`, and get all the results, then you can use the [Completion suggestor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) and you can even go through [UAX URL Email Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html)