# Elastic Search_as_you_type case insensitive match

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, tokenize

I want to perform partial search on 3 fields: UUID, tracking_id, and zip_code. They only contain 1 word and no special characters/space except hypen for UUID.
I'm not sure whether I should use search_as_you_type or edge ngram tokenizer or edge ngram token filter, so I tried search_as_you_type first.

I have created this index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "sort.field": [ "created_at", "id" ],
            "sort.order": [ "desc", "desc" ]
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "keyword", "fields": { "raw": { "type": "search_as_you_type" }}},
            "current_status": { "type": "keyword" },
            "tracking_id":     { "type": "wildcard" },
            "invoice_number":  { "type": "keyword" },
            "created_at":     { "type": "date" }
        }
    }
}
```

and inserted this doc:

```
{
    "id": "SIGRID",
    "current_status": "unassigned",
    "tracking_id": "AXXH",
    "invoice_number": "xxx",
    "created_at": "2021-03-24T09:36:10.717672467Z"
}
```

I sent this query:

```
{"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sigrid",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this returns no result, but SIGRID, S, SIG returns the result. How can I make search_as_you_type query be case insensitive? should i use edge ngram tokenizer instead? Thanks

Comment: my bad, actually the search_as_you_type works case insensitively, i just need to put fields: id.raw or dont put fields at all

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom normalizer with a lowercase filter, lowercase filter will ensure that all the letters are changed to lowercase before indexing the document and searching. Modify your index mapping as

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "sort.field": [
        "created_at",
        "id"
      ],
      "sort.order": [
        "desc",
        "desc"
      ]
    },
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",         // note this
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer",       // note this
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "search_as_you_type"
          }
        }
      },
      "current_status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tracking_id": {
        "type": "wildcard"
      },
      "invoice_number": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sigrid",
      "type": "bool_prefix"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66792606",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "SIGRID",
          "current_status": "unassigned",
          "tracking_id": "AXXH",
          "invoice_number": "xxx",
          "created_at": "2021-03-24T09:36:10.717672467Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: do you mean that because the fields i used for partial search is only 1 word, i dont need to use edge n grams? after reading many tutorials i got confused and led to the wrong direction i think

Comment: if i already use that analyzer, why is the field type search_as_you_type still necessary to be used??

Comment: @nanakondor  For the above use case, you can use edge ngram also. But if you want to search for lowercase also, then you need to use `normalizer` as shown in the above index mapping

Comment: @nanakondor if you want to know more about how `search_as_you_type` field works, then please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273804/10348758

Comment: my bad, actually the search_as_you_type works case insensitively, i just need to put fields: id.raw or dont put fields at all